# Multiple CORS working for GET but not for PUT/POST with pre-flight requests Web api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

When I configure CORS in my Web.config like following, every thing works:

```
<customHeaders>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:3000"/>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS"/>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, cache-control, credentials, content-type, authorization, origin, X-Requested-With, X-dev-mode"/>
</customHeaders>
```

However, when I try to enable multiple CORS like this:

```
// Filename: Global.asax.cs
protected override void Application_Start()
{
   ApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
}

// Filename: ApiConfig.cs
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:3000,http://someOtherUrl.com/", "*", "*");
   config.EnableCors(cors);
}
```

It works for GET (i.e. getting content, etc) but, when using POST/PUT (i.e. saving content, etc) it gives this error in browser (Chrome) console

> Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:56214/api/1/content/SAVE. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The request is failing on OPTIONS. Please note that I do have custom handlers and my routes are also configured.
One more thing to mention is that the PUT/POST call to save content is an ajax call via react. Can that be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the trailing slash in your second URL. Change it to this and it works:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:3000,http://someOtherUrl.com", "*", "*");
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried removing the blank space to the Access-Control-Allow-Methods like

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
```